# TypeError when trying to run function on Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror, apply

I have a pandas dataframe called `month_values` with values such as the following:

| Area | Thrpt_A | Thrpt_B | Thrpt_C | Thrpt_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Galle | 9581.539079 | 6790.664649 | 8340.489900 | 5940.886763 |
| Colombo | 5948.006563 | 4245.619220 | 7084.931812 | 3915.933362 |

The datatypes are

```
Area             object
Thrpt_A          float64
Thrpt_B          float64
Thrpt_C          float64
Thrpt_D          float64
```

I've defined a function with nested if-else to be applied to this dataframe as follows:

```
def mark_func(df):
    if (df['Area'] == "Colombo"):
        if (df['Thrpt_A'] >= 8000):
            return 'A'
        elif (df['Thrpt_A'] < (8000)):
            if (df['Thrpt_A'] >= df['Thrpt_B']) and (['Thrpt_A'] >= df['Thrpt_C']) and (['Thrpt_A'] >= df['Thrpt_D']):
                return 'A'
            elif (df['Thrpt_B'] >= df['Thrpt_C']) and (df['Thrpt_B'] >= df['Thrpt_D']):
                return 'B'
            elif (df['Thrpt_C'] >= df['Thrpt_B']) and (df['Thrpt_C'] >= df['Thrpt_D']):
                return 'C'
            elif (df['Thrpt_D'] >= df['Thrpt_B']) and (df['Thrpt_D'] >= df['Thrpt_C']):
                return 'D'
    else:
        if (df['Thrpt_A'] >= 4000):
            return 'A'
        elif (df['Thrpt_A'] < (4000)):
            if (df['Thrpt_A'] >= df['Thrpt_B']) and (['Thrpt_A'] >= df['Thrpt_C']) and (['Thrpt_A'] >= df['Thrpt_D']):
                return 'A'
            elif (df['Thrpt_B'] >= df['Thrpt_C']) and (df['Thrpt_B'] >= df['Thrpt_D']):
                return 'B'
            elif (df['Thrpt_C'] >= df['Thrpt_B']) and (df['Thrpt_C'] >= df['Thrpt_D']):
                return 'C'
            elif (df['Thrpt_D'] >= df['Thrpt_B']) and (df['Thrpt_D'] >= df['Thrpt_C']):
                return 'D'
```

The output I'm expecting is as follows:

| Area | Thrpt_A | Thrpt_B | Thrpt_C | Thrpt_D | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Galle | 9581.539079 | 6790.664649 | 8340.489900 | 5940.886763 | A |
| Colombo | 5948.006563 | 4245.619220 | 7084.931812 | 3915.933362 | C |

However, when I apply the function using the following line of code:

```
month_values['Mark'] = month_values.apply(mark_func, axis=1)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ("'>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'", 'occurred at index 279')
```

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here. Would be grateful for any suggestion to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the code:

```py
... and (['Thrpt_A'] >= df['Thrpt_C']) and (['Thrpt_A'] >= df['Thrpt_D']):
```

should be:

```py
... and (df['Thrpt_A'] >= df['Thrpt_C']) and (df['Thrpt_A'] >= df['Thrpt_D']):
```

Note the `df`